# Heroku does not respect npm-shrinkwrap.json

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I have a Node.js app with `npm-shrinkwrap.json` checked in. When I run `npm install` locally, it installs the versions specified in `npm-shrinkwrap.json`, but when I push it to Heroku (on the Cedar stack), it seems to ignore the shrinkwrap and simply installs the newest version.

Am I doing something wrong? I don't need to to check in `node_modules`, do I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say in your answer, when Heroku wrote the Nodejs buildpack, the feature `npm shrinkwrap` didn't exist.

However, as of version 1.1.2, `npm install` tries `npm-shrinkwrap.json` first, falling back to `package.json`. This means that Heroku respects it (even though the feature hadn't been conceived when Heroku wrote their code). Isaacs is awesome.

So just add to your `package.json`:

```
"engines": {
  "node": "0.8.x",
  "npm": ">=1.1.2"
}
```

Then run `npm shrinkwrap`, and `git add npm-shrinkwrap.json`. Then commit as normal.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, Heroku uses npm 1.0.106 at the moment, but `shrinkwrap` was only added in npm 1.1.2, according to the [changelog](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/blob/master/doc/cli/changelog.md).

Adding `node_modules` has solved my problem, until Heroku upgrade their npm.

Comment: If you specify `"engines": {"npm":  ">=1.1.2"}` per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-versions , Heroku's npm will respect `npm-shrinkwrap.json` if it exists.